# Java Spring Batch - executing from a jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have created one spring batch project. It executes perfectly as Java application. After that I created a jar file using maven build. But when I tried to run the jar file, the below exception is thrown:

```
=================================================================================
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 142 in XML document from class path resource [SICBatchFile.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'job'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'job'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more

=================================================================================
```

It's getting through the mail class. But when reading the xml, it throws this exception.  Below is the xml part:

```
  <beans:beans 
        xmlns="ht tp: / /www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
        xmlns:beans="ht tp: / /www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:aop="ht tp: / /www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:tx="ht tp: / /www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="ht tp: / /www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:xsi="ht tp :/ /www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="ht tp: / /www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="ht tp: / /www.springframework.org/schema/beans  ht tp: / /www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
        ht tp: / /www.springframework.org/schema/batch  ht tp: / /www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.0.xsd
        ht tp: / /www.springframework.org/schema/aop  ht tp: / /www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
        ht tp: / /www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        ht tp: / /www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

     <job id="sicProcessorJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
        <step id="step1">
        <tasklet transaction-manager="jobRepository-transactionManager">
            <chunk reader="sicFileItemReader" processor="sicProcessor"
                writer="sicFileItemWriter" commit-interval="3">
        <streams>
            <stream ref="sicFileItemWriter1"/>
            <stream ref="sicFileItemWriter2" />
          </streams>
        </chunk>    
    </tasklet>
    </step>
    <listeners>
      <listener ref="jobListener" />
    </listeners>
  </job>
```

IDE: Eclipse

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650252/problem-starting-spring-application-from-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After that I created a jar file using maven build. But when I tried to
>   run the jar file

if you just created a simple jar file, then it can't work, the application needs all libraries (spring, commons, etc.)

you can

- set the [classpath](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) or configure it with a [manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)
- use maven to create (see [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523997/unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace-http-www-sp/8574629#8574629))

  - executable all-in-one.jar
  - directory structure with all you need including a  .bat/.sh which sets the correct classpath