# No declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'

Tags: spring, google-app-engine

i'm starting with Spring 3 (3.1.2) and Google App Engine.

I've followed a tutoria online, now, i've my bean-realted xml which has a problem while starting.

this is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="my.example">
```

where the root package of all the java file is "my.example". The subpackage are "model" and "controller" with subpackages as well.
now.

when i start the app i receive back this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'.
```

with a lot of more stacktrace.

does anyone know how i can solve this?
i checked the XSD and they seems to be correct.

Comment: putting -3.1 for the xsd doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing spring-context.jar, that is the one which contains the definition for context schema.

Comment: i actually add ALL the library just to be sure. but notihing changed.
PS: there's no "spring-context" , there's "context", "context.support"

Comment: doesn't sound right @EsseTi, there should have been a spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar , unless you are using osgi jars distributed by Spring.

Comment: can you provide a link from where download the jars?
anyway the problem was in the XML since i didn't close the `<context:component-scan base-package="my.example">` right after but at the end of the file (i took this from an online example).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps any, but I had an error very similar to yours while using the [maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to make a single .jar, and the shade plugin wiped out the `spring.handlers` and `spring.schemas` from `META-INF/`.

This SO answer pointed me in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3650844/7008

And the document on using an AppendingTransformer to add those spring bits back in to your `META-INF/` folder did the trick for me: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#AppendingTransformer

Comment: This worked for me. Please consider adding the maven transformer configuration to to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is incompatible schema locations with your spring-context dependencies.

Replace

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
```

by

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
```

That should do the trick! I was using spring-context 3.1.1 and I was getting the same error referring to http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.1.xsd

However, you should also do a maven tree dependendency and check if you've got different spring versions. This error could be due to this fact also...