# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'

Tags: spring

I am using Spring **3.2.3.RELEASE** with maven to pull the dependencies. When building the project in Eclipse am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 17 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/application-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 64; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'.
```

My appication-context.xml has the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
```

I know that I am pulling the correct jar files as my Maven Dependencies shows:

[image: Eclipse Maven Dependencies]

Inside the META-INF/sping.schemas I can see that I have the right schema declaration in my jar:

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd
```

I have also looked at these to no avail:

[Can't load spring 3 schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687511/cant-load-spring-3-schemas)

[The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058037/the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-tx)

[No declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440928/no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-contextcomponent-scan)

[The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589470/the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-co)

Please help, it's driving me crazy .... :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For starters you should fix your dependencies. You are mixing Spring 3.2.3 and 2.0.6 jars (that is problems waiting to happen).

Next to that your declaration is wrong `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/` must be `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context`.

Comment: Ooo gosh thanks; didn't even see that; removing that final "/" did the trick ... will get on to sorting out those dependencies.

Comment: Same stuff. We must have copy/paste the same tutorial with this `/` at the end